# Discord.py on_message cancelling other commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to build a simple bot that can kick, ban, and say "Hi" to a member. Kick and ban work perfectly fine and do their job, but when I add an "on_message" function, the on_message function works but cancels out kick and ban. Any ideas?

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)


@bot.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "!hello" == message.content:
        await message.channel.send(f"Hi")
    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run("my token")
```

Comment: just a thought: why don't you implement `!hello` as a bot command? It seems like it's doing exactly what a bot command would do. also, take a look at this alternative implementation on just listening for `on_message` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working

Comment: Originally, I was going to make it a command, but I couldn't figure out how to send a message if it wasn't an `on_message` function. Thanks

Comment: It's pretty much in the introduction, simply `await ctx.send("Hi")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would make `!hello` a command:

```
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author=ctx.author
    await ctx.send(f'Hello, {author.mention}!')
```

Then change your on_message function to:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

I usually keep event functions before the commands for organization's sake. Here though, unless you'll have something else to check for when a user sends a message, I don't think you technically need an `async def on_message`/`await bot.process_commands` event.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience events and commands don't do well when they are in the same file, consider using [cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html) to seperate them.